# Implementación de GA4 y GTM a una app de ionic

Tags: angular, ionic, google-analytics, capacitor

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una app en ionic con capacitor a la cual le pidieron que se implementara analytics ga4 junto con gtm para el manejo de etiquetas, al momento de implementarlo me encontré con un foro en el cual recomiendan cargar los js tanto de GA4 y GTM

Link de referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64331925/22024243

GA4

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXX"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('js', new Date());
  </script>
```

GTM

```
<script>(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
      w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
        'gtm.start':
          new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
      }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
          'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
```

Seguido de eso, en el punto más alto de la app le asigno el id de seguimiento de GA al JS

```
startTrackerWithId(id : string) {
    gtag('config','G-XXXXXX');
  }
```

Y el evento lo envió de la siguiente forma

```
 trackEvent() {
    gtag('event', 'intento_ios', {});
  }
```

Al momento de inspeccionar la web si carga de forma correcta y todo bien de igual manera en la versión de Android pero en iOS no funciona igual carga los js correspondientes y cuando le doy click al botón para emitir el evento no sucede ningún error y no emite nada

Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano